# Email Action showing up in Chatter component only for System Admin profile (for Case records)

Tags: email, case, chatter

I am running into a weird problem where I can only see the "Email" action (created on Case object) for the Chatter component if I am on the System Administrator profile. Moving to another user for testing (attached to another profile) doesn't show the "Email" action.

This is how it looks as a System Admin
[image]

This is for logged in as another user

[image]

The settings that I checked for both profiles were:

[image]

[image]

Is there anything else I am missing?